Remove object id from array when referenced document expires
I have the following schema in my App:
const storySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    createdAt: { type: Date, expires: 10000 , default: Date.now },
    title: {type: String},
    creator: {type: Mongoose.types.ObjectId, ref: "User"},
    tags: [{type: String}],
    ....
})

currentSchema.index({"createdAt": 1 },{ expireAfterSeconds: 10000 });

The code above adds an index to ensure every story document is removed after 10000  ms. This code works correctly.
However I have a user schema designed like so:
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    stories: [{ type: Mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: "Story" }],
    title: {type: String},
    bio: {type: String},
    ....
})

When a story is automatically removed/expired I would like to automatically remove that story from the stories array of objectids which is stored on the creators document. I tried adding a pre('remove') middleware on the User model, however this isn't fired when a document expires.

You will need to write custom logic such as an periodical script. When using a TTL index there is a TTL thread that runs as a background task every 60 seconds and removes documents, not elements. Even if you add a TTL index to an object in an array the whole document will be removed - not what you want. When this happens it's usually code sniff that your data modelling is still in development. You already have a ref to the user in the creator field of the story schema. Is that not enough? If you really want you can add a virtual like in this.

@jQueeny Hello, could you please explain how could a virtual help me in this situation? I would remove the stories array from the User schema and add a virtual method instead? Is this correct?

Sure. I've given an example of how to set-up a virtual.

To use a virtual property first remove the stories field from your userSchema and then update like so:
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    title: {type: String},
    bio: {type: String},
},{
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
});

userSchema.virtual('stories', { 
    ref: 'Story', 
    localField: '_id', 
    foreignField: 'creator' 
});

You will note the use of toJSON and toObject options set to true. This ensures your new virtual stories field will be sent to your front-end if using res.json() etc.
Now you can use Model.populate() to get all of the documents from the stories collection where the Story.creator field matches the User._id and will ensure no expired documents reside in your user documents. Populating this way will only fetch stories that are live at the moment the query is made.
const user = await User.findOne({bio: 'something'}).populate('stories');
const users = await User.find().populate('stories');


Perfect thank you for your answer. Just to clarify, can you use virtual fields inside a $lookup within an aggregate query instead of the standard populate field?

Also, if stories field is an array of ObjectId refs instead of a single Ref to one document, will this virtual code still be appropriate? Thanks


Virtuals aren't in scope when you do an aggregate so you can't access them. That's fine because you you would just do a standard $lookup in the aggregate to get the same result. For example: { $lookup: { from: "stories", localField: "_id",  foreignField: "creator", as: "stories" } }. 2. You want stories to be an array. It can have 0 or more stories in it. You wouldn't want it to reference a single story as I presume a user could be the creator of many stories. That is the definition of one-to-many relationship. Otherwise it's a one-to-one, which doesn't sound like it really is.


Ok, So when using Model.aggregate() you cannot use virtuals, but to accomplish the exact same thing, you would just use a standard $lookup like you provided right?

That's correct.
